# Looking for a way to turn of my monitors, where they won't turn back on until I command them to

Tags: windows-10, display

I'm trying to use my pc for steam streaming when I'm not sitting in front of it. I would like to avoid having to turn off all 3 of my monitors physically. Therefore, I'm looking for a program or a script to turn them off (standby). I found a bunch of ways to do it, but they always wake up as soon as my mouse moves or when I launch steam remotely. I'm hoping to find a way to turn them off so that they will only wake up once I run the command to wake them (wake only on keypress would also work). I can create a macro to run the commands, but I don't know what the commands would be. I would really appreciate any help regarding this matter.

Thank you

Comment: Probably the only thing that will do this for you is a remote control power switch. There are many of these (Internet Search).  So it is probably best for you to get what suits you best.

Comment: I was hopping to find a script or a program to do it, but ya I guess If there is no other way, I might as buy one these. Thx

Comment: I do not think there is a script to turn off a monitor until desired. Monitors are not particularly smart, Just light up when given a signal via the video port. So the monitor needs to be turned off.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to control the signal that is sent to the monitor via the video port rather than to control the monitors behavior directly, but in the end I guess I'll just go with a physical switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen scripts to turn monitors off and on upon demand.

The best thing, then, for hardware devices such as Computers, Network Gear and Monitors that will turn devices off and then on upon demand is a remote control power switch.

There are many of these (Internet Search). So it is probably best for you to get what suits you best. I found many of these so whatever works for you is the best thing for you.

Comment: Ya I was hoping for a software, but I guess a smart power bar that is controlled trough software is close enough. Thank you

Comment: That should work for you and you are most welcome,

Answer (score 1):

If your using HDMI then HDMI CEC via USB could be for you.

https://www.pulse-eight.com/p/104/usb-hdmi-cec-adapter

Now the bad news is you have 3 monitors so that $120 in adapters.
So there is a physical command to turn the monitors ON/OFF via CEC built into hdmi.

Run your script and it sends the ON command to all 3 devices at once and turns them ON.

So that is going to require 3 USB port and/or USB hub.

---

Another alternative is KASA TP link hs300
https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1433487-REG/tp_link_hs300_smart_wi_fi_power.html

You can plug each monitor into a different port.
Then you can use the APP on your phone to control it.
You can even create a group to turn them ON/OFF.

In addition users on github have created a python API so you can control it that way also using python.
https://github.com/p-doyle/Python-KasaSmartPowerStrip

Additionally you can tie it to Google or Alexa devices to turn things ON/OFF using voice command.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. 2 out of the 3 monitors are using DP, but I like your idea about a smart power bar. It's the closest thing to using a software.

Comment: I use python to control and access the data with the hs300, so you can use software.